# How do I append a song to a currently playing playlist in a Spotify app?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I have a simple spotify (JS) app and I want to either:

- Create a new playlist with the first track and play it, or
- Append the song to the currently playing playlist

  ```
   var playlist = new models.Playlist();

   ...

   var search = new models.Search(query);

   search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
      if (search.tracks.length) {
        var track = search.tracks[0];
        playlist.add(track);
        if (!models.player.playing) 
           models.player.play(track, playlist);
      }     
    });

    search.appendNext();
  ```

Shouldn't this simply append the new track to the existing playlist? (playlist is scoped higher up, and it is definitely not re-created each time).

Currently nothing happens when a track is playing.

Comment: interestingly, it only plays playlists that are created without a name. this makes them "temporary" and assigns them a URI. however, appending to these temporary playlists doesn't work. if i create a named playlist via `new Playlist("name")` then it correctly appends tracks, but refuses to play it (perhaps because it lacks a URI)...

Answer (score 1):

it actually does work, but the playlist view takes a long time to render as updated. (although it immediately appends the track - as can be seen by clicking next). as mentioned in the comments however, it doesn't play a playlist when created with a name, only ones that are temporary and thus have a URI.

Comment: did you get crossfading to work? I'm facing the same problem, adding to a temp playlist causes the song to play immediately, but crossfading doesn't work.

Comment: I got it to work only if the song was added to the playlist prior to current song playing(you would need to maintain 2 songs on the playlist, that is it wouldn't check if new songs had been added to queue until the current song ended..). this was several months ago though now.